# How to customize color The line-through text decoration on tailwind css

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

i want customize width line "line-through" become more thick like 4-6px. i have customize thick line "line-through" on tailwind.config.js but it not works, maybe you can give me suggest about my problem.

```js
//setting tailwind.config.js in plugin:[]    
function ({addUtilities}) {
      const extendLineThrough = {
          '.line-through': {
              'textDecoration': 'line-through',
              'text-decoration-color': 'red',
              'text-decoration-width': '4px'
          },
      }
      addUtilities(extendLineThrough)
 }
```

```html
<div class="hidden sm:block md:col-span-2 text-rigt">
  <p class="md:pt-1 text-gray-500 line-through">
    Rp. 8000
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct css property is `text-decoration-thickness` so your plugin should be:

```
function ({addUtilities}) {
  const extendLineThrough = {
      '.line-through': {
          'textDecoration': 'line-through',
          'text-decoration-color': 'red',
          'text-decoration-thickness': '4px'
      },
  }
  addUtilities(extendLineThrough)
}
```

[Here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MCPUggXq8s?file=config)'s a working version on Tailwind Play.

Comment: thanks Jheath, it works for thickness line-thorugh